# What does this seal stamps on chinese painting mean?

Tags: seal

Thanks a lot for your help,

Simon
[image]

Comment: I'd interpret the last character (bottom left) as「廔」rather than「樓」.

Comment: @droooze, me too; it should be "廔". imo, it's incorrectly used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the reading sequence should be

```
miea
njfb
okgc
plhd
```

i recognised these characters:

a: 芳 http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=%E8%8A%B3

b: 艸 http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=%E8%89%B8

c: 有 http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=%E6%9C%89

d: 情 http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=%E6%83%85

i: 雁 http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=%E9%9B%81

k: 南 http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=%E5%8D%97

l: 浦 http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=%E6%B5%A6

m: 人 http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=%E4%BA%BA

n: 倚 http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=%E5%80%9A

o: 西 http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=%E8%A5%BF

therefore, i guess the seal is something like this:

> 芳草有情．夕陽無語．雁橫南浦．人倚西樓

well, i wish the op would provide a higher resolution, and brighter photos of this seal; have fun :)

edited.

i agreed with @vuluvsa, that character k is 飛 (u+98db); and, @droooze, that character p is 廔 (u+5ed4):

[http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=廔](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=%E5%BB%94)

well, i have difficulty, **not** to think that it's used incorrectly.

"西廔" cannot be treated as the same as "西樓".

so, imo, it's a serious mistake.

Answer (score 4):

> 芳草有情，夕陽無語，雁橫南浦，人倚西樓。

This sentence is a part of 宋詞 (a form of classical Chinese poetry
)《風流子·木葉亭皋下》 written by 張耒.

`張耒（1054年－1114年），字文潛，號柯山，生於楚州淮陰（今江蘇淮安市），祖籍亳州譙縣（今安徽亳縣）。北宋詩人。`

The whole article is shown below.

> 木葉亭皋下，重陽近，又是搗衣秋。
>   奈 愁入庾腸，老侵潘鬢，謾簪黃菊，花也應羞。
>   楚天晚，白蘋煙盡處，紅蓼水邊頭。*** 芳草有情，夕陽無語，雁橫南浦，人倚西樓。***
>
> 玉容知安否？香箋共錦字，兩處悠悠。
>   空恨碧雲離合，青鳥沉浮。向風前懊惱，芳心一點，寸眉兩葉，禁甚閑愁？
>   情到不堪言處，分付東流。

This poem describes the feeling of yearning for his wife.

However, the maker of the seal has changed one word, i.e., 橫 to 飛。

雁橫南浦 --> 雁飛南浦

The meaning is the same.